# Java Swing JTable data collection fails on last cell

Tags: java, jtable

I am trying to collect data from a JTable by using the method below to an array.

```
public String[][] getTableData (JTable table) {
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();      
    String[][] tableData = new String[nRow][nCol];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
        for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++)
            tableData[i][j] = (String) dtm.getValueAt(i,j);
    return tableData;
}
```

Everything works fine but I am not able to get data of the last row last column. No error is given. When I change the loop range, I get an arrayoutBound error.

The method that returns is below:

```
public void setGrid(String data [][], String header []){
    dtm.setRowCount(0);
    dtm.setColumnCount(0);
    dtm.setDataVector(data, header);
    tbl1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(25);
}
```

I have edited the method like as below to get the data captured.

```
public String[][] getTableData (JTable table) {
    String dat= new String();
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
    String[][] tableData = new String[nRow][nCol];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
        for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++)
            dat=dat + (String) dtm.getValueAt(i,j);
            bb.Toplabel.setText("data is :" +dat);
            //tableData[i][j] = (String) dtm.getValueAt(i,j);
    return tableData;
}
```

The data displayed is null even though the cell has value.

Comment: How do you know that *ot able to get data of the last row last column* ? What really returns the last row/column call from the table model?

Comment: i save this to an array and load the data from the array back to the table.

Comment: This part of the code looks good; What's the code putting it back in the table?

Comment: public void setGrid(String data [][], String header []){
  dtm.setRowCount(0);
  dtm.setColumnCount(0);
  dtm.setDataVector(data, header);
  tbl1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(25);
 }

Comment: i am using the method below

Comment: i am using the method below                                                                                                          public void setGrid(String data [][], String header []){
  dtm.setRowCount(0);
  dtm.setColumnCount(0);
  dtm.setDataVector(data, header);
  tbl1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(25);
 }

Comment: Can you reformat that so it's readable, please?

Comment: i have added the method above.

Comment: Do you need to use DefaultTableModel? Why you don't collect data directly from table?

Comment: can you suggest another way to do it?

Comment: I don't know the rest of the code, but I worked for me to replece a 'dtm' in method getTableData() to 'table'. I can read data, but i don't know how you use it after collection.

Comment: JTable do not have a method like that

Comment: I know, getTableData() is your method form code above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76449/discussion-between-obonyo-and-m-cekiera).

Answer (score 0):

You had it almost right but forgot to store dat in the array.
Also casting object to the String doesn't make it String. Better way is to get String by toString() method or simply treat Object as String in other operator like plus(+).
Here is right and simplified code:

```
public String[][] getTableData (JTable table) {
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
    String[][] tableData = new String[nRow][nCol];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
        for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++) {
            String dat=""+ dtm.getValueAt(i,j);// this will be always the String
            bb.Toplabel.setText("data is :" +dat);
            tableData[i][j] = dat;
        }
    return tableData;
}
```

One more thing - always use curly braces in your code. Even for one line in the loop. It will help you avoid errors when you add more lines of the code to the loop body.